# Subtract one second from given CTime

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am working on a VC++ project using MFC. There's a CTime object in my function that has a value of "10/11/2016 03:00:00".......something like that.

I want to subtract one second from the time part. So it will look like

"10/11/2016 02:59:59"

So for e.g., if the CTime value is "10/22/2016 07:45:50" then after subtraction by 1 second it should be "10/22/2016 07:45:49"

I tried,

CTime - 1, but this gives an error.

**UPDATE:**

I fixed this via,

```
time_t myTime= CTime.GetTime();
myTime= myTime - 1;
```

time_t gives the time in seconds and thus it's straight forward at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add or subtract to or from a `CTime` you need to use a [`CTimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7zw4wy1.aspx) object to indicate the duration you want to add or subtract.

For example, to subtract a second:

```
CTime cNewTime = cOldTime - CTimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: I fixed it using the method i just added as UPDATE. Am still voting your answer for the kind suggestion.

Comment: @Donsan: The code provided in this answer is a lot more readable than your proposed solution. It explicitly conveys the author's intent (*"subtract a time span"*), which should always be your primary goal.